# Restricting input to a true statement in set mutator

Tags: java, set, mutators

This is a simple question, When I create a new object class of "concert" how can i restrict it with joptionpane dialog boxes, When I run it the program does not seem to care if i've set a boolean restriction. I can put in 25 for the month and it takes it just fine and in a outputstring it shows "25" with no error.

```
if (userInput.equals("1")) {
       do{
        String artist = getStringInput("Artist or Group name?");
        int month = getIntegerInput("Enter month in XX format ");
        int day = getIntegerInput("Enter day in XX format ");
        int year = getIntegerInput("Enter year in XXXX format");
        int ticketCost = getIntegerInput("Enter cost per ticket ($25 - $250)");
        int quantTickets = getIntegerInput("Enter Number of tickets available (Max 10,000)");  
        int concertId = 1000;    
        concert[numConcert++] = new Concert(artist,quantTickets,ticketCost,month,day,year,concertId);
```

Class

```
   private String artist = "";
   private int quantTickets = 0;
   private int ticketCost = 0;
   private int month = 0;
   private int day = 0;
   private int year = 0;
   private int numConcert = 0;
   private int concertId = 1000;

  public Concert(String artist, int quantTickets, int ticketCost, int month, int day, int year, int concertId){
  this.artist = artist;
  this.quantTickets = quantTickets;
  this.ticketCost = ticketCost;
  this.month = month;
  this.day = day;
  this.year = year;
   this.concertId = concertId;
} 


   public boolean setMonth (int month){
        if (negative(month)) return false;
        if (month > 12) return false;
          this.month = month; 
         return true;
 }

    public int getMonth (){
        return this.month ;
  }
```

Comment: Where do you call your `setMonth` method?

Answer (score 0):

You say "this.month = month". You must call the setMonth(int month) method here.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean exactly?

Comment: this.month = month sets your global variable "month" to the parameter "month" which you give it upon creating the object.

So, you need to do something like :

if (setMonth(month)) {  
 this.month = month;   
}  
else {  
 //error message or whatever  
}  

EDIT: Sorry about rubbish formatting.

Comment: So where do you do the conditions when do you that?

Comment: In the if(setMonth(month)) you call the method. It will only be true if the month value meets your conditions and only then do you set this.month = month. Otherwise, you can do an error message or something.